# I am not able to create OneToOneField and ForeignKey field with User model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I have these two model

```
class TaskModel(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start=models.DateField()
    end=models.DateField()
    note=models.CharField(max_length=300)

class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='profileimg',blank=True)
    desc=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    martial=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

But when I run `makemigrations` command then it shows me this error::

> app.TaskModel.users: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
> HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.

This is my problem, I made `TaskModel` as a `ForeignKey` but it working like `OneToOne` Field.

Comment: That's not an error, iit is a warning. `ForeignKey`s that are unique is basically what a `OneToOneField` is. `primary_key=True` implies `unique=True`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an *error*, it is a *warning*. `ForeignKey`s that are unique is basically what a `OneToOneField` is. `primary_key=True` implies `unique=True`, hence the `user` field of your `TaskModel` can better be turned into a `OneToOneField`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class TaskModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`TaskModel`</s> to `Task`.